# c# detect client disconnection from server

Tags: c#, client-server

I've got a server and 2 winform clients(for a tictactoegame). Can I detect a client disconnection instantly ?. First opened client is player1 socket and 2nd is player2. Once both clients are connected player1 has to click a button and player2 buttons are all disabled. After player1 clicks a button player2buttons are enabled and player1 buttons disabled...so on

isConnected method

```
public  bool IsConnected(Socket socket)
{
    try
    {
        return !(socket.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && socket.Available == 0);
    }
    catch (SocketException) { return false; }
}
```

Server code

```
public class ServerApp
{
    public Socket serverSocket;

    Socket player1;
    Socket player2;
    ServerGame myGame;

    public ServerApp()
    {
        myGame = new ServerGame();
        serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, 
                                  ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8221);
        serverSocket.Bind(ipLocal);
        serverSocket.Listen(4);

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for clients ...");
        player1 = serverSocket.Accept();
        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 joined");
        player2 = serverSocket.Accept();
        Console.WriteLine("Player 2 joined");

        myGame.InitGame();

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                myGame.Display();
                Console.WriteLine();

                myGame.Send(player1, BaseGame.Player.One);
                myGame.Send(player2, BaseGame.Player.Two);

                if (myGame.GetActivePlayer() == BaseGame.Player.One && 
                    myGame.IsConnected(player1)==true)
                {
                    myGame.Receive(player1);                       
                }
                else if(myGame.IsConnected(player1) == true)
                {
                    myGame.Receive(player2);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);                    
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Server going down");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServerApp serverApp = new ServerApp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "instantly". A computer can't do anything _literally_ instantly any more than you or I can. A graceful closure of the socket can happen very quickly though, depending on the network connection. A reset (dropped connection) may or may not be detected quickly, depending on what else is going on. You should be more specific about what you're asking.

Comment: Let's say player1 has to click a button, then player2 buttons are disabled. If I close player1 , how can I detect that I closed it(it waits for player2 to click a button but player2 buttons are disabled). If I wouldve close player2, when I click player1 I get a message on the console(player 2 disconnectetc)

Comment: Is there a line of code that is causing you problems in the sample above?

Comment: should this be checking if `player2` is connected instead of `player1`? `else if(myGame.IsConnected(player1) == true) { myGame.Receive(player2); }`

Comment: @Rufus, no it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

The player being closed should gracefully shutdown the socket before exiting. This involves calling `Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)`, and then waiting for a receive operation to return a byte count of 0 (indicating the remote client has also shutdown).

This will ensure timely closure of the connection. Otherwise, the other player not being closed will have no way to know that the connection was lost until they attempt to send some data.